# how to transition between fragments in Kotlin after x seconds without clicking (like a splash screen)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments, android-transitions

I have 2 fragments: splash screen and login. I want the splash screen to appear first then go automatically to the login page.
here is the navigation nav_auth.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/nav_auth"
app:startDestination="@id/splashScreen">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/splashScreen"
    android:label="fragment_splash_screen"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_splash_screen" />



<fragment
    android:id="@+id/loginFragment"
    android:label="fragment_register"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_login" />


  </navigation>`
```

I want to add animation and time limit but the question is how to transition to a fragment and not the whole activity? Can I do this using intent?

```
   //Animations
    val topAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.top_animation)
    val bottomAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.bottom_animation)

    //Hooks
    val image = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageView)
    val slogan = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)

    image.setAnimation (topAnim)
    slogan.setAnimation (bottomAnim)

        Handler().postDelayed({
            val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, AuthActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        },3000)
```

Comment: I think adding a fake loading is redundant. Anyways, I would separate the splash into a different Activity as it is unrelated to the rest of the app flow. You can check this tutorial for a great Splash Screen implementation: https://medium.com/geekculture/implementing-the-perfect-splash-screen-in-android-295de045a8dc

Comment: You really have two questions here: (1) how to do something after a delay and (2) how to animate a fragment transition using the navigation library. You already know 1 from your code above. And 2 is [in the documentation here](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-animate-transitions). Regardless, Android 12 will have built-in splash screens. You'll need to account for that or your app will have two splash screens on Android 12. And my personal opinion is that fake splash screens that artificially delay when you can start using the app are super annoying.

Answer (score 0):

IMO it is unnecessary and frustrating for users sometimes having to wait for loading to finish which is for nothing. But anyhow if you really want to implement it, you can refer to this documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-animate-transitions)